# How to attach stdin and stdout to the user process invoked by call_usermodehelper

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

After learning little bit of call_usermodehelper() and lots of trials, it executed successfully.
Here's the code:-

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/umh.h>
static char *argv[] = {"/bin/sh","-c","/home/san/Temp/my_prog",0};
static char *envp[] = {"HOME=/","TERM=linux","PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",0};
static int __init userspace_start(void) {
    printk("Start...\n");
    call_usermodehelper(argv[0],argv,envp,UMH_WAIT_PROC);
    printk("End...\n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit userspace_exit(void) {
    printk("Exit\n");
}
module_init(userspace_start);
module_exit(userspace_exit);
```

```
// my_prog.c
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        printf("Testing\n");
}
```

I'm working on Linux Kernel 4.15.0-29-generic

Now, the problem I'm facing is that I'm not getting any output on terminal. After searching I found that I need to attach stdin and stdout, also I found to override stdin and stdout. So, I got confused about 'attach/override' stdin and stdout. I'm actually noob at this and wanted to learn the stuffs about the linux kernel. So, can I get sample code about how to attach/override stdin and stdout so, that I can see output on terminal after spawning user-space program from call_usermodehelper or which steps I should follow to achieve this.

I also found call_usermodehelper_pipe but got no luck i.e when I execute:`grep -r "call_usermodehelper_pipe" /usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic/include/linux/` I didn't got any declaration about it.

I also read that "Spawning stuff from the kernel should be only done in extremely special circumstances". But I'm doing this for learning purpose.

Thank you so much in Advance!

Comment: What you are asking for does not make much sense, not even for educational purposes really, it's like learning how to shoot a bow to prepare for a chess tournament. With this said, you *should* be able to just redirect the output through the shell executing something like `{"/bin/sh","-c","/home/san/Temp/my_prog > /dev/tty1",0}` and then go check the result on TTY1 by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1 (then use CTRL+ALT+F7 to get back to the graphical session).